# How to insert coordinates as variables into javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates, google-street-view

I would like to ask a simple question... i have this command
`getBase64FromImageUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=37.28,24.67&size=300x300&pitch=90")`
in a Javascript scenario. How can i insert the coordinates into that, as variables? I tried to state before it:
`x=37.28` and `y=24.67` and then to replace them with x and y, but the command doesn't understand it x and y as those coordinates. I want to do that, because the coordinates will be produced that moment and i won't be to able to know them before. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: Are you asking about concatenating strings in javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this!
this uses ES6 notation [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
let x= 37.28 ,y= 24.67
let myString = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=${x},${y}&size=300x300&pitch=90`
getBase64FromImageUrl(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

var x=0, y=0;

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
  console.log( x +"----"+ y );
});
```

Can get mouse coordinates